# What would be a good Database terminology to define sprocs, functions, views, triggers, column constraints, indexes?

Tags: function, stored-procedures, indexing, view, constraints

*Stored procedures, 
*functions, 
*views, 
*triggers,
*column constraints
*indexes
....
...

are Not pure Data.  In other words, the aforementioned aspects of a database are Not Data.

What would be a good Database terminology to define the above Aspects in the Database technology field?

Answer (score 1):

They are [database objects](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24081/database-object). Database objects are described with [Data definition language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language).